# What can heroes be commended for?

Tags: overwatch

In the commendation screen, after a match, you can see a few players who were picked out because of something "big" that they contributed to the team. For example, you'll see commendations like:

- McCree: *x* Fan The Hammer kills
- Reinhardt: *x* damage blocked
- Mercy: *x* healing done
- Pharah: *x* rocket direct hits
- etc.

What I'm curious about is what kind of commendations are there for heroes?  Everytime I see a Reinhardt commendation window, it only ever says "*x* damage blocked", and I have never seen something like "Eliminations done" or "Damage Dealt", despite these categories being something you'd see without fail on S76 and Reaper commendations.

So do heroes have access to all possible statistics to be commended for? Meaning, say using Soldier 76, then he could possibly have a commendation for:

- Damage done
- Medals awarded
- Eliminations
- Rocket Direct Hits
- Healing done

Or are heroes only specifically limited to certain commendations? Would it ever be possible to see Mercy being commended for "most damage done" if Mercy had actually dealt most damage compared to every other hero, or would the commendations be restricted to "healing done, assists, revives, etc."

Comment: If commendations were per-team, it would be easy to check all those videos when people all go one character... But then the other team would get all the non-class-specialty commendations.

Comment: I've no proof but it makes absolutely no sense for every hero to have access to all commendations. Blizzard made the game so that each character should be playing their role well regardless of what that is. A damage dealer should be dealing damage (and receiving damage commendations), a tank should be absorbing damage (and receiving damage blocked/absorbed recommendations) etc. Besides, how would anyone but a McCree get a fan kill recommendation 0.o ?

Comment: @JoãoNeves What my point is, there are other things that Mercy could be commended for but I have never seen in game, such as damage dealt, damage boosted, eliminations, etc.  It is very possible, albeit rare, that a Mercy manages to out dps every other hero

Comment: @O-O I get that but like I said Mercy shouldn't be doing that and should not be encouraged to do that so I believe (but have no proof) she can only get commended for actions that fit her role. I believe this because Blizzard went to extreme lengths to make everyone play as a team and play their role within the team (they even removed the scoreboard and K/D ratios).

Comment: Giving Mercy damage commendations would be like _encouraging_ rambo medics; It might work, but please don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Redditor SpriteGuy_000 has done some extensive testing, and according to his [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb7xg_EmtkqgR7da6IDMcFjdEsFkefcW_78mAIRKp0w/edit#gid=608177062) these are the things you can be commended for.

#### All Heroes

- [Eliminations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay1Bn.png) (% Kill Participation)
- Objective Time
- [Damage Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5PBF.png) (% of Team Damage)
- [Gold Medals Earned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VN99.png) (Total Medals)
- Total Medals
- [Objective Kills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7hGO.png) (Eliminations)
- [Best Kill Streak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeDpq.png) (Eliminations)
- Teleporter Pads Destroyed (Enemy Teleporters Placed)
- [MVP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQpkz.png) (% of Match on Fire)
- Melee Final Blows (% of Final Blows)
- [Environmental Kills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXTxR.png) (Eliminations)
- [Solo Kills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7XxQ.png) (Eliminations)

#### Bastion

- [Recon Kills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UodpC.png) (Eliminations)

#### D.Va

- Mechs Called (Mech Deaths)

#### Genji

- [Damage Reflected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd7vL.png) (Deflection Eliminations)
- [Dragonblade Kills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH325.png) (Dragonblades)

#### Hanzo

- Doesn't appear to have any unique commendations

#### Junkrat

- Players Trapped

#### Lúcio

- [Healing Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XZYG.png) (% of Team Damage Taken)
- Sound Barriers Provided (Sound Barrier Casts)

#### McCree

- [Fan the Hammer Kills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HxvC.png) (Total Eliminations)

#### Mei

- [Enemies Frozen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niVK8.png) (Total Time Frozen)
- Damage Blocked

#### Mercy

- Players Resurrected (% of total deaths)
- [Healing Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVPVm.png) (% of Team Damage Taken)
- [Defensive Assists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSdm2.png) (% Kill Participation)

#### Pharah

- [Rocket Direct Hits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ9gt.png) (% of Rockets Fired)
- Barrage Kills (Rocket Barrages)

#### Reaper

- Souls Consumed ()
- Death Blossom Kills (Eliminations)

#### Reinhardt

- [Damage Blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZRK8.png)

#### Roadhog

- Self Healing (% of Damage Taken)
- [Enemies Hooked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U96Fy.png) (% Hook Accuracy)

#### Soldier: 76

- Helix Rockets Kills (Eliminations)

#### Symmetra

- Players Teleported (% Teleporter Uptime)
- [Sentry Turret Kills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jf2b.png) (Eliminations)
- Shields Provided (% Shield Uptime)

#### Torbjörn

- Armor Packs Created (% Armor Uptime)
- [Turret Kills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIGsF.png) (% Kill Participation)

#### Tracer

- Health Recovered (Recalls Used)

#### Widowmaker

- Infra-Sight Uptime (Recon Assists)

#### Winston

- [Damage Blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aesRE.png)
- Jump Pack Kills

#### Zarya

- Projected Barriers Applied (Damage Blocked)

#### Zenyatta

- Transcendence Healing (Healing Done)
- Healing Done (% of Team Damage Taken)
- [Defensive Assists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2wxf.png) (% Kill Participation)

Comment: I would like to add that D.Va can get a commendation for "Mechs Called" with a subcommendation for "Mech Deaths", and S76 can get a commendation for Helix Rocket Kills

Comment: Reaper can get a commendation for Death Blossom Kills

Comment: I think this answer is incomplete, but its a great start, and the community can add to it over time.

Comment: As for Mercy's "Players resurrected", the value in brackets is "% of total deaths" (not sure on the exact wording).

Comment: If anyone can back this up, does Zarya have a Shield Uptime commendation as well? I feel like I've seen them before although I haven't played her in a few days.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I have played her quite a bit, and have not noticed this ever.

Comment: Zarya has high energy kills and Genji can technically get healing via reflect.

Comment: I've started adding screenshots as photo evidence for each commendation

Comment: Zarya also has average energy and high energy kills commendations. Pretty sure Hanzo has scatter arrow kills too, but I can't confirm that.

Comment: D-va can also get a recommendation for damage blocked using shield

Comment: @KizTrap I think I also so scatter arrow kills for hanzo but also not sure. Can anyone confirm this one?

Answer (score 5):

Without any official data published anywhere that I can see, I can only speculate on my answer, using personal experience from both the closed and open beta, as well as many games played the last two days.

Essentially, from what I can tell, it seems that every character has the opportunity to get a few "core" commendations that are common among all of them. These likely include Eliminations, Solo Kills (questionable, see below), MVP, and Damage Done. I'm not sure if anyone has played every hero enough to confirm that any of the general commendations are impossible to achieve on a particular character, but just harder to do so among a group of 12 players (Solo Kills on Lucio for example. Not to imply that Lucio is difficult to get kills with).

Additionally, for each character, it seems there are commendations for each of their unique mechanics, include their Ultimate. Enemies Frozen for Mei, or Rocket Direct Hits for Pharah, for example.

Lastly, there are a few commendations that are limited to a character's ability to perform them. Characters that cannot move other characters should not get Environmental Kills, just as characters that cannot produce a barrier cannot get Damage Blocked. (Note that Zarya's ability to produce a Barrier would likely result in her getting a commendation for Projected Shield uses rather than the more general Damage Blocked). In a similar vein to these abilities are those that are limited to a character's role. I am unsure if Solo Kills falls into this category for Offense heroes, and right now that limits Damage Blocked to Tank heroes (unless I am forgetting someone).

Again, this is based on my experience, and I cannot find any definite rulings. Such data would be hard to find this early into the game without definite word from Blizzard.

Comment: I don't want to busy up the answer, but the question of commendations gets more interesting when you consider the fact that sometimes less than 4 are available, especially if one team gets rolled (defeated handily). This implies that there is a "weight" or "score" the commendation must meet to appear at the end. This leads one to question whether the "more specific" commendations are weighed more heavily than the "less specific".

Comment: From my experience with Zarya, I will only get Shield Uptime as opposed to Damage Blocked.

Comment: Rather than "Shield Uptime" it is "Projected Barriers Given/Provided" with a sub-value of "Damage Blocked" on the same card. I have not seen a "Shield Uptime" commendation, personally. I've probably played ~15 hrs of Zarya between the beta and now, so someone more experienced might be more knowledgeable.