# How can I stay on fire?

Tags: overwatch

As stated [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/264763/127901), being on fire means you are doing well, and [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/269529/127901) we see that you can be commended as an MVP for being on fire for a large portion of the time.
This [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/269870/127901) shows that destroying non-player things gives you fire points, but what all do I get points from, and how many fire points do I need to be on fire/stay on fire?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm on fire. So?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264759/im-on-fire-so)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft that question asks what being on fire means, this question asks about how to stay on fire/gain fire points.

Comment: The answers for the other question cover much of the same ground. Hard to say for sure.

Comment: @twobugs Remember, two distinct questions with similar answers are still two different questions.

Comment: I agree, but these questions are inherently very similar. If we're not counting the answers, even then they're arguably similar enough.

Comment: `How can I stay on fire?` you ask? By listening to my mix tape of course.

Comment: *"He's on fire!"*  Sorry... once an NBA Jams fan, always an NBA Jams fan.  I couldn't help myself.

Comment: I am the dupe and I endrose this question.

Comment: Talk about clickbait.

Comment: Make sure you keep hitting those field goals and banking in the threes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To be on Fire, you need at least 250 fire points (fire). Your fire meter can hold infinite fire, but displays 350 as max, and you fire will decay at 5 fire per second.

## Getting fire:

### Eliminations

"All Heroes gain Fire based on
% damage done to enemies during
Eliminations
(i.e. 50% damage dealt = 50 Fire)"

### Deployable Eliminations

- D. Va's Mech 100 Fire
- Junkrat's Concussion Mine 1 Fire
- Junkrat's Steel Trap 1 Fire
- Junkrat's RIP-Tire   50 Fire
- Symmetra's Sentry Turret 25 Fire
- Symmetra's Teleporter    100 Fire
- Torbjorn's Turret    100 Fire
- Widowmaker's Venom Mine  25 Fire

### Objectives

- Payload Escort   5 per sec
- Payload Checkpoint   55
- Capture Point Capturing  180 total
- Capture Point Checkpoint 55
- Control Point Capturing  100 total
- Control Point Checkpoint 10

### On-fire Rates

**Ana**

- 1 fire per 5 hp healed

**Bastion**

- Healing  1 Fire per 5 HP healed

**D. Va**

- Blocking 1 Fire per 25 Damage Blocked

**Genji**

- `UNKNOWN`

**Hanzo**

- Recon Assist 40 Fire per Assist

**Junkrat**

- `UNKNOWN`

**Lúcio**

- Healing  1 Fire per 5 HP healed

**McCree**

- `UNKNOWN`

**Mei**

- Blocking 1 Fire per 25 Damage Blocked
- Healing  1 Fire per 5 HP healed

**Mercy**

- Healing  1 Fire per 5 HP healed
- Support  50 Fire per Resurrect
- Kill Assist  1 Fire per Assist?

**Orisa**

- Blocking 1 Fire per 25 Damage Blocked

**Pharah**

- `UNKNOWN`

**Reaper**

- Healing  1 Fire per 5 HP healed

**Reinhardt**

- Blocking 1 Fire per 25 Damage Blocked

**Roadhog**

- Healing  1 Fire per 5 HP healed

**Soldier: 76**

- Healing  1 Fire per 5 HP healed

**Sombra**

- `UNKNOWN`

**Symmetra**

- Support  25 Fire per Shield
- 25 Fire per Teleport

**Torbjörn**

- Support  25 Fire per Armor Pack used by allies
- Healing  1 Fire per 5 Turret HP healed

**Tracer**

- `UNKNOWN`

**Widowmaker**

- Recon Assist 40 Fire per Assist

**Winston**

- Blocking 1 Fire per 25 Damage Blocked

**Zarya**

- Blocking 1 Fire per 25 Damage Blocked

**Zenyatta**

- Healing  1 Fire per 5 HP healed
- Kill Assist  1 Fire per Assist?

[Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb7xg_EmtkqgR7da6IDMcFjdEsFkefcW_78mAIRKp0w/edit#gid=786726912)
Note: ?'s indicate unconfirmed stats.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm fairly certain that killing Junkrat's Rip-Tire gives 50 fire.

Comment: @Shaffanhoon Possible, I will have to science this again. I'll add a "?" to it for now.

Comment: @Shaffanhoon I believe that his tire has 100 hp - if you get 50% of elimination damage as fire - 50 fire would only make sense.

Comment: Dying seems to tank the on-fire meter, is this just due to the natural loss of 5 per second?

Comment: @Cassius40k for me I usually can stay on fire after dying if I wasn't just barely on fire. Death lasts 10 seconds, so you lose 50 fire to that, plus 5 per how ever many seconds you take to get back to the fight and start getting more fire. I have stayed on fire for an 2 rounds straight on KotH even while dying several times each round, so I think it is due to the natural decay, though it is something that should probably be scienced a bit more.